# How to post to the wall like the admin of a page using the Facebook JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a JavaScript function which have been used to post something to the wall of the current user. But when I go to a Page (Fanpage), which I am the admin of, it's:

```
function postToWall(id, title, desc, href, image, caption)
{
    FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'feed',
            app_id: social_app_id,
            name: title,
            link: href+'?ref='+social_user_id,
            picture: image,
            caption: caption,
            description: desc
        },
        function(response) {
            // nothing to do here
        }
    );
}
```

But I got the error:

> An error occurred with My App Name. Please try again later.

How can I post to the admin wall to include tile, desc, image, and caption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify both `from` and `to` parameters for `Feed Dialog`.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  name: title,
  link: href,
  picture: image,
  caption: caption,
  description: desc,
  from: 'ID_OF_PAGE_ADMIN_OR_PAGE',
  to: 'ID_OF_PAGE'
}, function(response) {
  // nothing to do here
});
```

If `from` and `to` is the same id `to` can be skipped since it's defaults to `from` value.

**Update**:
You can fill `from` and `to` with id of your Facebook Page and post as Page itself, not just Admin of Page